# Invalid parameter for sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I  know this appears to be a common problem and that it's based on the specific name of the parameters, but I'm still getting an error after looking at the keys.

```
steps=[('classifier', svm.SVC(decision_function_shape="ovo"))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Specify the hyperparameter space
parameters = {'estimator__classifier__C':[1, 10, 100],
              'estimator__classifier__gamma':[0.001, 0.0001]}

# Instantiate the GridSearchCV object: cv
SVM = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv = 5)

_ = SVM.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Which I then get:
`` ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator ... Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`. ``

So I  then look at `SVM.get_params().keys()` and get the following group, including the two I'm using. What am I missing?

cv
error_score
estimator__memory
estimator__steps
estimator__verbose
estimator__preprocessor
estimator__classifier
estimator__preprocessor__n_jobs
estimator__preprocessor__remainder
estimator__preprocessor__sparse_threshold
estimator__preprocessor__transformer_weights
estimator__preprocessor__transformers
estimator__preprocessor__verbose
estimator__preprocessor__scale
estimator__preprocessor__onehot
estimator__preprocessor__scale__memory
estimator__preprocessor__scale__steps
estimator__preprocessor__scale__verbose
estimator__preprocessor__scale__scaler
estimator__preprocessor__scale__scaler__copy
estimator__preprocessor__scale__scaler__with_mean
estimator__preprocessor__scale__scaler__with_std
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__memory
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__steps
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__verbose
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot__categories
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot__drop
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot__dtype
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot__handle_unknown
estimator__preprocessor__onehot__onehot__sparse
**estimator__classifier__C**
estimator__classifier__break_ties
estimator__classifier__cache_size
estimator__classifier__class_weight
estimator__classifier__coef0
estimator__classifier__decision_function_shape
estimator__classifier__degree
**estimator__classifier__gamma**
estimator__classifier__kernel
estimator__classifier__max_iter
estimator__classifier__probability
estimator__classifier__random_state
estimator__classifier__shrinking
estimator__classifier__tol
estimator__classifier__verbose
estimator
iid
n_jobs
param_grid
pre_dispatch
refit
return_train_score
scoring
verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your param grid should be `classifier__C` and `classifier__gamma`. You just need to get rid of `estimator` in the front because you named your SVC estimator as `classifier` in your pipeline.

```py
parameters = {'classifier__C':[1, 10, 100],
              'classifier__gamma':[0.001, 0.0001]}
```